# Disable autoinserted closed quote in ruby-mode emacs

Tags: ruby, emacs

I use ruby-mode for emacs, when I enter quote ", automatically inserted closed quote.

This is maybe useful, but when I edit code it prevents, how I can disable this "feature"?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have

```
(require 'ruby-electric)
```

in your emacs config? If so, remove it.

Using `ruby-mode` alone doesn't cause the magic quotes you're seeing. Check also that you don't have `autopair-mode` enabled.